# Get a concrete type and create instance of interface type parameter?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

Let say I the construcor,

```
    public MyClass(Manager<Iinterface> manager)
    {
         // How can i get the type of Iinterface and then create an instance
    }
```

Is it possible that I can make this constructor generic? like,

```
    public MyClass<T>(Manager<T> manager) where T is Iinterface
    {
         // How can i get the type of Iinterface and then create an instance
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "concrete type of interface"? I.e. what would be "concrete type" for `IEnumerable` for this question?

Comment: You cannot make the constructor generic. But you can make the whole class generic.

Comment: I mean whoever called this method will provide a concrete type?

Comment: @Dmitry, Thanks but I can't make the class generic, this is restriction

Comment: Can you show how you expect caller to "provide concrete type"? Looks like you are not showing all arguments of constructor (i.e. one that specifies the concrete type).

Answer (score 1):

You need to define this with the class itself, not the constructor. If you can't make the class itself generic, then static "Create" method could do this. But the, there is probably problem of passing the instance of `Manager<T>` to `Manager<Iinterface>`, because classes cannot be covariant.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Manager<Iinterface> manager) 
    {
        // How can i get the type of Iinterface and then create an instance
    }
    public static MyClass Create<T>(Manager<T> manager) where T : Iinterface, new()
    {
        Type tType = typeof(T);
        T tInstance = new T();

        return new MyClass([some parameters]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't make the class Generic :(

Comment: I am getting, `Must have a public parameterless constructor`

Comment: +1: if you can't make class generic than generic creator function is probably the only option (if you want to stick with having it inside class).

Comment: @user960567 you need to align restriction with your requirements - since you have not shown your code that creates new instance of "concrete class" the only reasonable option is to assume `new()` restriction and call parameter less constructor in sample.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, the problem is that Manager and Iinterface are in third party library I can't change it. Now I am trying, `_userType = typeof(Manager<>).GetInterface("Iinterface").GetGenericArguments()[0];`